# Cloud message does not receive on console?

Tags: c#, azure, iot

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace eNtsaIOTMqttApp
{
    class Program
    {

        // you can get DeviceConnectionString from your IoT hub

        private const string DeviceConnection = "HostName=eNstaIot.azure-devices.net;DeviceId=GcobaniTesting1;SharedAccessKey=*********";
        static ServiceClient serviceClient;
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            serviceClient = serviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString);
            Program prog = new Program();
        }

        public Program() {
            DeviceClient deviceClient = DeviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString);
            SendEvent().Wait();
            ReceiveCommands(deviceClient).Wait();
        }

        // This method is responsible for sending Event to Iot Hub.

        static async Task SendEvent()
        {
            string dataBuffer = "IOT in 90 seconds";
            Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Message eventMessage = new Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Messages(Encoding.ASCII);
            await serviceClient.SendAysnc("GcobaniTesting1", eventMessage);

        }

        // this method is responbile for receive message on the IOT hub.
        async TaskReceiveCommands(DeviceClient deviceClient)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("\nDevice waiting for IoT hub command...\n");
            Microsoft.Azure.Devices.Client.Message receiveMessage;
            string messageData;
            while (true)
            {
                receiveMessage = await deviceClient.ReceiveAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
                if(receiveMessage != null)
                {
                    messageData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveMessage.GetBytes());
                    Console.WriteLine("\t{0}> Message received: {1}", DateTime.Now.ToLocalTime(),messageData);
                    await deviceClient.CompleteAsync(receiveMessage);
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Why am i not receive the message on my console when i am running this console application? I do get iot device, but when i send message from iot hub i dont get on visual studio.
is there some useful link to this rule?

Comment: Hi Gcobani, remember not to post your passwords as part of your code - I have blanked them out.

Answer (score 0):

This line is wrong:

```
serviceClient = serviceClient.CreateFromConnectionString(DeviceConnectionString);
```

You must use the service-side connection string to create the ServiceClient, for example the IoTHubOwner connection string. You are trying to create your service client with the device connection string. This should actually throw an error.

See here for guidance on connection strings: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/iotdev/understand-different-connection-strings-in-azure-iot-hub/
[image]

Comment: I have follow the above steps, still could, what im getting now is new and different. Here is complaint about my SendEventMessage() function, when i send the message  to the device.

Comment: here is what? Did you mean to post an error message?

Comment: yes i having a new error now, UnauthorizedException;

Comment: I having a new error now from my SendEvent().Wait(); UnauthorizedException. What am i missing exactly? The message doesnt pass this method and it throws an error. I might think im sending an incorrent DeviceID due to serviceID for being misonfigure with DeviceID on my IOTHub. Am i wrong to say so why on my object declaration ServiceClient serviceClient = new ......  rather be DeviceClient s_deviceClient = new DeviceClient();